# Mongo can't be pulled error: Mongodb on Kubernetes DeploymentSet

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to set up a MongoDB pod on Kubernetes by pulling directly from docker for a Microservices application I am working on but I keep getting the error : "mongo can't be pulled". I am also managing multiple deployments with Scaffold with the scaffold dev command, this mongo error terminates the scaffold command thereby closing all other services in the cluster. This is my yaml file

I have tried the settings below in. the yaml config file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  minReadySeconds: 5    
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth-mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-mongo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth-mongo
          image: mongo
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
            
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth-mongo
  type: ClusterIP  
  ports:
    - name: db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some strange reason I do not know I tried it with the yaml code untouched and it worked.

Comment: Thanks to share the solution with the community. Please, close the question. If you could detail more the solution, it will be appreciated. Welcome!